# What is the difference between $|a|$ and $|| a ||$

Tags: cross-product

So I am doing maths involving cross-product and dot-product and I came across the above two notation as in $||u\times v|| = ||u|| ||v|| \sin a$ and $u\cdot v = |u| |v| \cos a$. What is the difference between $||u||$ and $|u|$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are different notations for the same thing:  the magnitude of a vector.

Comment: Any reason for writing them in this way.

Comment: Writing $\|v\|$ instead of $|v|$ makes it more clear that one is talking about the *norm* of a vector; $|a|$ is used to denote the absolute value of a real number, $a$.

Comment: But |a| is a vector out here, I know that it is used to find the absolute value, but in the case above it is not used in such a way.

Comment: Not especially. You can perhaps tell more instantly whether the magnitude of a *vector* or the magnitude of a *scalar* is intended. I think it's a little silly to distinguish since the nature of the creature between the bars completely determines which it is. You can't apply vector magnitude operation to a scalar, and you can't apply scalar magnitude to a vector. Besides, using the same symbol for both leads to a very nice formulation that extends the case where the vector space is the same as the scalar field; namely, that $|au|=|a|\;|u|$.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "$|a|$ is a vector out here$. Using tuple notation for vectors, you can write $|(3,4)|=\sqrt{3^2+4^2}=5$, and |-2(3,4)|=|-2||(3,4)|=2(5)=10$.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, darned site won't let me edit the comment. But I think you can see what I intended.